# drag scroll on a fixed button

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, scroll

If you look here:

https://jsfiddle.net/8s8uamhq/1/

You'll see a bunch of blue and green boxes.  You can scroll right and left, up and down on this page with the normal scroll bars on the window.

I'd like to change it so that if you click and hold the arrow key in the right hand corner, you can scroll that way, and as you scroll the arrow key still stays in place.

The purpose is to add this to a web app, so that it can be used on tablets with this button to scroll, while touching the screen can be used for other things.

the full html for the js fiddle page looks like:

```
<html>
  <head>

    <title></title>
    <meta content="">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

    <style>
    #movearrow {
        position: fixed;
        top: 45px;
        right: 20px;
        z-index:99999;
        font-size: 2.5em;
        text-shadow: 0px 0 white, 0 2px white, 0px 0 white, 0 -2px white;
        cursor: grab; cursor : -o-grab; cursor : -moz-grab; cursor : -webkit-grab;
    }
    .blue, .green {
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
    }
    .blue {
        background-color: blue;
    }
    .green {
        background-color: green;
    }
    .column {
        float: left;
    }
    div {
        display: inline-block;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

  <span id="movearrow" class="dragscroll glyphicon glyphicon-move"></span>

  <div class=column>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
  </div>

  <div class=column>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
  </div>


  <div class=column>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
  </div>

  <div class=column>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
  </div>

  <div class=column>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
  </div>

  <div class=column>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
  </div>

  <div class=column>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
  </div>

  <div class=column>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
  </div>

  <div class=column>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
  </div>

  <div class=column>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
  </div>

  <div class=column>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
  </div>

  <div class=column>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
    <div class=blue > </div>
    <div class=green > </div>
  </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To trigger events on click/mousedown/touch you're going to want to use either jQuery or JavaScript. I've used jQuery 2.1.3 for my solution but you could probably write it in Pure JS too.

I've also inserted fake links inside your #movearrow span so that we can have the page scroll up when the top arrow is clicked, left when the left arrow is clicked, etc.

HTML:

```
<span id="movearrow" class="glyphicon glyphicon-move">
    <a href="#" id="left"></a>
    <a href="#" id="top"></a>
    <a href="#" id="right"></a>
    <a href="#" id="bottom"></a>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
#movearrow a {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    z-index: 9999999;
    display: block;
}

#movearrow a#left {
    left: 0;
    top: 25%;
    bottom: 25%;
    right: 50%;
}

#movearrow a#right {
    right: 0;
    top: 25%;
    bottom: 25%;
    left: 50%;
}

#movearrow a#bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 25%;
    right: 25%;
}

#movearrow a#top {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 50%;
    left: 25%;
    right: 25%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $top = $("#top"),
        $left = $("#left"),
        $right = $("#right"),
        $bottom = $("#bottom");
    var scrollPxW = $(".column").children().first().outerWidth(); // horizontal amount scrolled
    var scrollPxH = $(".column").children().first().outerHeight(); // vertical amount scrolled
    $("#movearrow").children("a").click(function() {
        return false; // removes function of anchor link
    });
    $bottom.on({ // for the bottom arrow
        'mousedown touchstart': function() {
        // animate scrollTop position of body & html
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: "+=" + scrollPxH + "px"
            });
        },
        'mouseup touchend': function() {
        // when hold event finishes, stop animation
            $("html, body").stop(true);
        }
    });
    $top.on({
        'mousedown touchstart': function() {
        // animate scrollTop position of body & html
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: "-=" + scrollPxH + "px"
            });
        },
        'mouseup touchend': function() {
        // when hold event finishes, stop animation
            $("html, body").stop(true);
        }
    });
    $right.on({
        'mousedown touchstart': function() {
        // animate scrollLeft position of body & html
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollLeft: "+=" + scrollPxW + "px"
            });
        },
        'mouseup touchend': function() {
        // when hold event finishes, stop animation
            $("html, body").stop(true);
        }
    });
    $left.on({
        'mousedown touchstart': function() {
        // animate scrollLeft position of body & html
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollLeft: "-=" + scrollPxW + "px"
            });
        },
        'mouseup touchend': function() {
        // when hold event finishes, stop animation
            $("html, body").stop(true);
        }
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8s8uamhq/1/

If you want to have it on click instead of on click+hold, you can just use a click event, like:

```
$top.click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop:"-=" + scrollPxH + "px"
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Did you save in jsfiddle?  Your answer has my old link in it rather than an updated link.

Comment: Thanks for the illustration.  It is saved here: https://jsfiddle.net/8s8uamhq/3/ .